# Laravel 502 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5.3 with the latest Homestead Setup. When I make a POST Request to my API, I get this error according to the log file:

> 2016/10/29 12:44:34 [error] 776#0: *28 recv() failed (104: Connection
>   reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   192.168.10.1, server: loc.medifaktor, request: "POST /api/v1/mfusers HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock$

I use POSTMAN to make the POST Request sending it to the URL:
http://loc.medifaktor/api/v1/mfusers

which is a homestead installation and runs locally on my computer.

The client address mentioned in this error is 192.168.10.1 which is actually not true, as I use 192.168.10.10. Could this be the mistake and how do I change that?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am using a fresh install of Laravel and I tried other requests like GET which work fine. Just the POST Request throws this error.

The php-fpm.log shows:

> ```
> [29-Oct-2016 13:47:15] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
> ```

This is the output of the nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name loc.medifaktor;
    root "/home/vagrant/Development/Source/MFServer/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/loc.medifaktor-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/loc.medifaktor.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/loc.medifaktor.key;
}
```

Comment: could you show your PHP-FPM error logs?

Comment: I only found the file php-fpm.log in the var/log folder (edited question)

Comment: The error log is not clear enough... 
But maybe you can try to set `catch_workers_output = yes` on your php-fpm configuration file. It will redirect worker stdout and stderr into main error log.

Comment: I added the nginx config as well if that helps?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your nginx config I guess.. I've the same problem with you a few months ago. And these were what I did. Update the `pm.max_requests` to 500 and restart the fpm service, `sudo service php5-fpm restart`. Hope it will work for you too.

Comment: Where do I set this?

Comment: You can set it on php-fpm configuration file. `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf`

Comment: nope didnt change anything

Comment: i'd check iowait as well. if `i/o wait` is high, it may cause the problem. In the past i have tested Drupal 7 and had many of errors caused by iowait (on Xen virtual machine).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `fastcgi_pass` to `127.0.0.1:9000` in your website's nginx `sites_enabled` conf file.

Comment: It's crazy, but it was the only thing that helped in my case. It'd be great to know why this change is needed.

Answer (score 6):

If you recently ran sudo apt-get update and installed a new version of PHP, and use nginx, make sure you've updated your fastcgi_pass setting in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, e.g.:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
```

You should also make sure you install the latest version of the pdo_pgsql extension.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that your PHP version must match your indicated fastcgi_pass fpm. sock. For example, you have php version 7.4. then you should use the code below.

```
fastcgi_pass unit:/run/php7.4-fpm.sock
```