# PHP opcache causes function failure

Tags: php, nginx, opcache

## What is the situation?

- 2 websites: **A** and **B** ( laravel5.2 )
- **A** want to using **B**'s `javascript` file
- **B** is using `opcache`
- **B** using `git` update codes and  `post-hook` request specified `URL` reset `opcache`

**website A codes:**

```
<script src="https://B/controller/getJsFunction"></script>
```

**website B codes:**

```
public function getJsFunction()
{
    header('Content-Type:application/javascript');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    //mix('/js/visitor.js') will get visitor.js and auto add the current version
    echo file_get_contents(rtrim(public_path(), '/') . mix('/js/visitor.js'));
}
```

## What I want?

- website **A** get the website **B**'s `javascript` file content
- **B** can upgrade the `javascript` file version number any time, `visitor.v1.js` => `visitor.v2.js`

## What happened?

**B** sustain return `502` `HTTP` status code after a period of successful operation,
When **B** Modified any code trigger `opcache_reset()`, even just add comments, the `bug` will fix a while.

## What I have?

`nginx` log

```
2018/05/06 03:56:17 [error] 12747#0: *28155344 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxxxxxx, server: xxxxxxx.com, request: "GET /stateless/visitor/js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xxxxxx.com", referrer: "https://xxxxxx"
```

`git` post-receive

```
cd /path/to/site-B/project
unset  GIT_DIR
git pull origin master && curl https://site-B.com/cache.php
```

cache.php

```
<?php
opcache_reset();
```

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  error;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include         /etc/nginx/black.ip;
    include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    keepalive_timeout   600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 20m;

    gzip                on;
    index       index.html index.htm index.php;

    server {
        listen 80 default;
        server_name _;
        return 403;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       443;
        server_name  site-b.com;
        root         /path/to/site-b.com/public;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /path/to/site-b.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/site-b.com.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4:!DHE;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        if ($scheme = http ) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$host$1 permanent;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|ico|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ 
        {
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME
                           $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

}
```

## What help I need?

- How to REALLY fix the bug?
- Or what other methods should I use?
- Or why `reset_opcache()` can fix the bug? Or why `opcache` causes this bug?

*Since this is an online project, I temporarily modified it to that **site A** first request **site B** to get the current version of the `javascript` file, and then insert a `script` tag and set `src` url from first  step response*

Comment: What is the function definition of `mix()`? That is not a PHP built-in function as far as I can recall.

Comment: Plain PHP will probably not return a 502. Does your web server error log on B provide any useful information?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `//mix('/js/visitor.js') will get visitor.js and auto add the current version`

Comment: [OPCache and APC(U) are interface context aware](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php#117957):  Meaning if you use the console (e.g. git hook) to execute `reset_opcache()`, the cache is only reset for the CLI interface based cache. I suggest instead to enable `opcache.validate_timestamps` and set `opcache.revalidate_freq` to 0 in your php ini. Additionally you should replace `echo file_get_contents()` with [`read_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: What else is executed within Site B's `getJsFunction`?  How is the route being served? Normally this would be caused when the server pool gets full and is forced to reset the connection. What is your nginx configuration for PHP? I'm not convinced this is isolated to an opcache issue.

Comment: @fyrye `getJsFunction` all codes is what I showed. I am using `post-hook` request specified URL to reset `opcache`. If it is not an opcache issue, why the problem fixed a while when I `push` some new comment?

Comment: Please show the hook that resets the opcache. This is sounding like an nginx php configuration issue to me. Since by default OPcache automatically invalidates the cache anytime the file is changed after 2 seconds, unless the settings we're changed.

Comment: @fyrye I added the file contents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 502 Bad Gateway Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319340/laravel-502-bad-gateway-error)

Comment: Please show us your nginx configuration for the server.

Comment: @fyrye nginx.conf added